# scanf from function to array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory, scanf

I am trying to scanf values to an array from another function using pointer to pointer. Here's the code:

```
int initialize(int **arr, int count);

int main()
{
    int count;
    int *numbers;
    scanf("Enter the amount of numbers to enter: %d", &count);
    initialize(&numbers, count);
    free(numbers);
    return 0;
}

int initialize(int **arr, int count)
{
    int i = 0;
    *arr = calloc(count, sizeof(int));
    while(i < count)
    {
        printf("Nr. %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It allocates the memory correctly, however, there seems to be a problem inside scanf function in initialize so it crashes after reading in first 2 numbers. Could you help solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arr` is a pointer to pointer to `int`, so 1st make it a pointer to `int` (before using it like an array) by doing `*arr`.

So this

```
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
```

should be

```
    scanf("%d", &(*arr)[i]);
```

or its shorter equivalent

```
    scanf("%d", *arr + i);
```

---

Unrelated, but in C it should be at least

```
int main(void)
```

---

Unrelated^2: Sizes and indexes in C best are defined using `size_t` (coming with `stdlib.h`).

So the relevant part of your code would look like this:

```
int main(void)
{
  size_t count;
  int *numbers;
  scanf("Enter the amount of numbers to enter: %zu", &count);
  ...

int initialize(int **arr, size_t count)
{
  size_t i = 0;
  *arr = calloc(count, sizeof(int));
  while (i < count)
  ...
```

---

Last not least the code misses error checking for the relevant functions:

- `scanf()`
- `calloc()`

Error checking (along with logging the errors) is debugging for free!

Comment: Thanks, it works. Where could I find more detailed information on this scanf pointer thing?

Comment: @gintas: This is not an issue with `scanf()` (is **always** takes the address of the variable to scan into), but your confusion about the levels of indirection you implemented ... ;)